# How to safely use new Linux functions?

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing code that uses sched_setaffinity, which requires kernel 2.5.8 or later.  I've been trying to find out if these things are possible:

1. Systems with older kernels to compile this gracefully, perhaps just ignoring that code segment entirely.
2. If I send someone with an older kernel a compiled binary, it will step over this function or simply print a warning.

I guess my question is, how do you use new kernel functions safely, without breaking the entire application when using an older system?

Comment: Stop worrying about 2.5 kernel series and anything before. Anybody who is still using those should be put into mental institution or something :)

Comment: @Nikolai: Quite a number of embedded Linux devices still run 2.4.x.

Comment: I'm sure they do. They also carefully build very restricted set of userland binaries, so that target group is not an issue here.

Comment: You will have more problems with the linked `libc` version than with the kernel.  As others pointed out, you can try to invoke a non-existent or not implemented syscall, and you will get `ENOSYS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to get your program to link or to run?  You can invoke the system call directly via the glibc `syscall()` function without needing a recent C library.  Obviously it's going to fail on earlier systems without support (a quick test shows the kernel returns -1 == ENOSYS for unimplemented syscall numbers), so you will need to test for that.

Answer (score 3):

Use `dlopen()` with `NULL` as the filename, and `dlsym()` the function you want to use. If the `dlsym()` succeeds, call the function through the function pointer that was returned.

Comment: Even if the symbol is in the libc, the call can still fail with `ENOSYS`.

Comment: Needlessly complicated.  Just use syscall().

Comment: Both of these sound like good options.  From what I can tell, the dlopen/dlsym() checks to see that the function exists. And the syscall() is just another way to call linux system calls, via glibc.  However, why have syscall at all?  What does this do other than add another layer of abstraction?  This solution looks promising, I just want to make sure it doesn't do anything else that might be unwanted.

Comment: Ah...it would appear I have found an answer myself.  This website explains the motivation for syscall nicely: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/System-Calls.html.  This sounds best, as dlopen/dlsym seem to be not so reliable for this purpose. @AndyRoss